# KSQL Rolling Sum

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

W have created a ksql stream that have id, sale, event as parameters where "event" can have two values, "sale" and "endSale". We used the below command to create the stream.

```
CREATE STREAM sales (id BIGINT, sale BIGINT , data VARCHAR)
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='raw_topic', VALUE_FORMAT='json');
```

We want to aggregate on the "sale" parameter. So, we have used SUM(sale) to aggregate it. We have used the below command to create a table

```
CREATE TABLE sales_total WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', KEY_FORMAT='JSON') AS
SELECT ID, SUM(SALE) AS TOTAL_SALES
FROM SALES GROUP BY ID EMIT CHANGES;
```

Now, we want to keep the sum aggregating as long as "event = sale". And, when the "event = endSale", we want to publish the value of SUM(SALE) AS TOTAL_SALES to a different topic and make the value of "SUM(SALE) AS TOTAL_SALES" to 0;

How to achieve the above scenario?

Is there a way to achieve this using UDAF? Can we pass custom values to UDAF "aggregate" function?

According to [this link](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/0.7.1-ksqldb/concepts/functions/)

> An aggregate function that takes N input rows and returns one output value. During the function call, the state is retained for all input records, which enables aggregating results. When you implement a custom aggregate function, it's called a User-Defined Aggregate Function (UDAF).

How to pass N input rows to the UDAF? Please share any link for example

Comment: Hi, just to confirm, do you want to emit a single value for each ID, or after a sale is closed, you can reuse that same ID and emit a new total for this?

Comment: What will happen when you receive new sale type events after an endSale event?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, so after the "endSale" if "sales" comes, it will start aggregating the from that sale. Previous aggregated sum should be reset to zero on getting an event type "endSale"

Comment: Hi @Jean-Sébastien, we want to use the same ID after the sale is closed and emit a new total